# Opposite for as much as possible

Tags: phrases

what's the opposite for the phrase

> Students try to do as much as possible

can i say

> Students try to do as less as possible ?

Comment: "Students try to do as *little* as possible."

Answer (score 4):

In that context, the antonym of *much* is *little*, or it might be better to say that the antonym of *as much as* is ***as little as***.

> Students try to do as **little** as possible.

Alternative formulations include "students try to do the minimum".